# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource' on Raspbian with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to deploy an application on Raspberry Pi. I have installed .NET Core Runtime and I have this error while executing:

```
    Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.ApplyServices (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptions options, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection services) [0x0003f] in <e66a1f96e9734a7fac7cea0901022728>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<GetOrAdd>b__2 (System.Int64 k) [0x000fe] in <e66a1f96e9734a7fac7cea0901022728>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`2[System.Int64,System.ValueTuple`2[System.IServiceProvider,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]].invoke_TResult_T(long)
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) [0x00034] in <69599a71bc4d4cd3a8a6e4323fa57b86>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptions options, System.Boolean providerRequired) [0x000b7] in <e66a1f96e9734a7fac7cea0901022728>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions options) [0x00051] in <e66a1f96e9734a7fac7cea0901022728>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor () [0x00006] in <e66a1f96e9734a7fac7cea0901022728>:0 
  at XPathParserTest1.Model..ctor () [0x00000] in <51b90b049f2c424c9ef8e7dced3213d4>:0 
  at XPathParserTest1.Program.MainAsync (System.String[] args) [0x001a2] in <51b90b049f2c424c9ef8e7dced3213d4>:0 
  at XPathParserTest1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00015] in <51b90b049f2c424c9ef8e7dced3213d4>:0
```

The same project files works fine on Windows with SDK and clean Windows with Runtime only.

I have no idea what is going on, I have tried some solutions with editing csproj file and changing nuget dependencies.

Comment: What is the build command you're using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 with "Publish" option to local folder.

Comment: Not sure how to do it through the UI, but try publishing the the command line: `dotnet publish --runtime linux-arm <pathtocsproj>` and see if you get the assembly in the resulting output folder.

Comment: I added `-c Release` to this command and it works! Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

For Raspbian it is a good idea to generate native image for the executable, if it is officially supported